# Excel VBA - Add an ActiveX TreeView Control to sheet with code

Tags: excel, vba, treeview, controls, activex

I'm trying to create an ActiveX TreeView Control on a sheet and name it via code.

Interestingly enough when I copy a sheet, the TreeView Control won't copy with it so my work-around is to just insert the Control via code. I dug around and couldn't find anything  about creating it with code.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the next piece of code, please. Only to guide you on the aproach:

```
Sub AddTreeControl()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, TrC As OLEObject, TC As Object
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  Set TrC = sh.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="MSComctlLib.TreeCtrl.2", link:=False _
        , DisplayAsIcon:=False, left:=200, top:=70, width:=150, height:= _
        200)
  Set TC = TrC.Object
  With TrC
    .Name = "TreeControlX"
    .Select
  End With
  With TC
    .nodes.Add Key:="item 1", Text:="Parent 1"
    .nodes.Add "item 1", tvwChild, Key:="one", Text:="ITEM 1, Child node 1"
    .nodes.Add "item 1", tvwChild, "two", "ITEM 1, Child node 2"
    
    .nodes.Add Key:="item 2", Text:=" Parent 2"
    .nodes.Add Key:="item 3", Text:=" Parent 3"
  End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks FaneDuru.

This is what I came up with:

```
Sub Test()
'Create an ActiveX TreeView, assign dimensions, and name
    With Sheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="MSComctlLib.TreeCtrl.2",_
        Left:=55, Top:=450, Width:=330, Height:=400)
       .Name = "InsertNameHere"
    End With
End Sub
```